# when I update weexpack it said weex sha1 checksnum failed

Tags: weex

I`m first use weex for hybrid APP, I had already

```
$ npm install -g weex-toolkit
```

but when I use weex for

```
$ weex run android
```

it tips me I should update my weexpack
and I do it

```
$ weex update weexpack@1.2.1
```

but it error 
it say

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-wVm41b4PnlpvNG2rlPFs4CIWG4g= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-wVm41b4PnlpvNG2rlPFs4CIWG4g= but got sha1-tDLdM1i2NM914eRmQ2gkBTPB3b4=.
```

what should I do now

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to delete C:\Users{user}.xtoolkit\node_modules\weexpack

then retry

`npm update -g weex-toolkit@new_version`

But it didn't work. So just `uninstall` and `install` again. Then it works